# How to write Viewport width/height in Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

When I check the official Tailwind CSS documentation, it says that

> Use w-screen to make an element span the entire width of the viewport.

I mean, w-screen is ok when I try to implement

```
width: 100vw;
```

But what should I do when I try to implement

```
width: 90vw;
height: 90vh;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The right approach to take depends on whether the values are going to be reused.

### Arbitrary Values

If there's one specific place that you need a value such as `90vw` rather than it being repeated, opt for an arbitrary value. Example:

```
<div class="w-[90vw] h-[90vh]"></div>
```

Classes for those styles will be generated automatically.

### Extending Your Config

For styles that are likely to be repeated or which should be part of your design system, extend your Tailwind config instead:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      height: {
        'screen/90': '90vh',
      },
      width: {
        'screen/90': '90vw',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Use:

```
<div class="w-screen/90 h-screen/90"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I find useful to create a plugin for this case

Change Tailwind config into this (add plugin and default values)

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

// create default values
const screenKeys = Array.from({length: 20}, (_, i) => i*5)
const screenSizes = screenKeys.reduce((v, key) => Object.assign(v, {[key]: key}), {});

module.exports = {

  // ...

  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({matchUtilities, theme}) {
      matchUtilities(
        {
          'w-screen': width => ({
            width: `${width}vw`
          })
        },
        { values: Object.assign(screenSizes, theme('screenSize', {})) }
      ),
      matchUtilities(
        {
          'h-screen': height => ({
            height: `${height}vh`
          })
        },
        { values: Object.assign(screenSizes, theme('screenSize', {})) }
      )
    })
  ],
}
```

It will allow you to use `w-screen` or `h-screen` utility with any `vw` or `vh` values from 0 to 95 with step 5 (0,5,10...95). `w-screen` with no values will be `100vw` (as current behaviour)

```html
<div class="w-screen h-screen-35">
  Default width screen is still working
</div>

<div class="w-screen-50 h-screen-[15]">
  50vw width, 15vh from JIT
  No need to set h-screen-[15vh] as we already know we're working with vh units
</div>
```

In your case it will be `w-screen-90 h-screen-90`

You may extend config for reusable classes with `screenSize` key

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screenSize: {
        33: 33 // just an example
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Usage

```html
<div class="w-screen-[22] h-screen-33">
  33vh from user config, 22vw from JIT
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/csYHvlKYj6)

Answer (score 0):

version 3.4 update

New size-* utilities: Set width and height at the same time, finally.

Ex: **size-10** it means w-10 h-10

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Tailwind CSS utility classes to set the width and height of an element to a specific viewport width or height.

For example, to set the width of an element to 90vw, you can use the class w-90. Similarly, to set the height of an element to 90vh, you can use the class h-90.

So, in your case, you can use the following classes:

```
w-90
h-90
```

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't work. '90' isn't a default value in Tailwind and if it were, the convention would be that it would map to a rem value. `w-96` for example is 24rem.

Comment: This is wrong. It doesn't work this way. Arbitrary values should be wrapped in square brackets with the desired unit, for example, `w-[90vw]`.