# With TailwindCSS how do I cap max height of viewport to 75%?

Tags: tailwind-css

Trying to limit the max height to 75% of the screen, but not sure how to achieve this using standard Tailwind classes.

I would assume these `max-h-screen-75`, `max-h-screen-50`, `max-h-screen-25` etc. would do the job, but unfortunately not.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74614394/how-to-write-viewport-width-height-in-tailwind-css/74620016#74620016) - replace height with max-height and same technique can be applied

Answer (score 5):

Tailwind-css only has a default `%` value for 100% (which is `max-h-full`).

To create a custom max-height, you have 2 options:

##### 1. [Arbitrary Values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-height#arbitrary-values):

HTML:

```html
<div class="h-12">
  <div class="max-h-[25%] bg-red-200 text-5xl">25%</div>
</div>

<div class="h-12">
  <div class="max-h-[50%] bg-green-200 text-5xl">50%</div>
</div>

<div class="h-12">
  <div class="max-h-[75%] bg-blue-200 text-5xl">75%</div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/OgFulJsfqO)

---

##### 2. [Customizing your theme](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-height#customizing-your-theme):

HTML:

```html
<div class="h-12">
  <div class="max-h-25 bg-red-200 text-5xl">25%</div>
</div>

<div class="h-12">
  <div class="max-h-50 bg-green-200 text-5xl">50%</div>
</div>

<div class="h-12">
  <div class="max-h-75 bg-blue-200 text-5xl">75%</div>
</div>
```

tailwind.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      maxHeight: {
        '25': '25%',
        '50': '50%',
        '75': '75%',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/LjbLZ6eL5Z?file=config)

---

#### Result:

[image: %]